WSL No Internet Connection (Ubuntu, Windows 11)
Clear Network/Internet Connection Problem:

ping google.com returns ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
pip install streamlit or other packages return network error message; same for sudo-apt install

My host machine (Windows 11) has no internet issues at all.
What I've Tried

Disable windows firewall entirely shutdown WSL and ping google.com again: doesn't work

Ran the following command to flush my dns on windows:


netsh winsock reset 
netsh int ip reset all
netsh winhttp reset proxy
ipconfig /flushdns

then restarted my computer: doesn't work

Updated my /etc/resolv.conf and /etc/wsl.conf to put nameserver of 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.8.4 and even make the /etc/resolve.conf immutable... and it doesn't work.

sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
sudo bash -c 'echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf'
sudo bash -c 'echo "[network]" > /etc/wsl.conf'
sudo bash -c 'echo "generateResolvConf = false" >> /etc/wsl.conf'
sudo chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf


Disabled "fast start-up" option in Power Options then restarted my comp... still doesn't work

Chnaged from my company WiFi to my personal mobile hotspot - doesn't work


Suspected Reasons

Change of network (VPN?) but disabling VPN doesn't yield a meaningful difference

Windows Update (including Quality Updates)


Somehow I have WSL update automatically with an old kernel version though my WSL Ubuntu is installed from Microsoft store?
enter image description here
But my WSL version seems to be okay
WSL version: 2.2.4.0
Kernel version: 5.15.153.1-2

Appreciate Any Help

I'm totally at a loss and would really appreciate any help!! My last resort is to uninstall WSL and reinstall :(


Is there a reason your not on 23H2?

To answer concisely: no there's no particular reason. I usually don't explicitly download particular updates; I only update when the update button pops up when I try to shutdown my computer.

It might be because your Ubuntu WSL is using a different network configuration and the resolv.conf changes are not having any effect.
You can verify if it is using systemd-resolved configuration via the following command:
systemctl status systemd-resolved

If it is enabled and active then you need to add a nameserver to this file: /etc/systemd/resolved.conf by adding:
DNS=8.8.8.8

After this change, restart systemd-resolved:
sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved
sudo systemctl status systemd-resolved

And finally verify if the changes are working via:
resolvectl status

This should return the DNS servers in use under the global section.
After this just use dig with any domain name to verify if the DNS resolution is working or not.

Thanks for a new solution. Unfortunately, I tried it and it didn't work. Ping to google.com or 8.8.8.8 still fail to resolve.
